# Maximum maximum of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am trying to find $x$ and $y$ that maximise this function, for $x$ and $y$ between $0$ and $1$.

$f(x,y)=\left(1 - (1-x)(1-y)\right)K - C(x) - C(y)$

with the following restrictions:

$$C > 0,~ 
C' > 0,~
C'' > 0,~
K > 0
$$
I tried to solve this by differentiating wrt $x$ and $y$, and setting the derivatives $= 0$. However, this didn't find the corner solution when $C''$ is close to $0$.  For example, if $K = 1$ and $C = \frac9{16}x + 0.1x^2$ then I get the following first order conditions: 
$(1-x) - \frac7{16} - 0.2y = 0$ and a symmetric one replacing $y$ and $x$. Solving these I get $x = y = \frac{45}{88}$.

This is a local maximum, but if I use $x = 0$, $y = 0.9$, I get a higher value (approx $0.42$) vs the value at $x= y = \frac{45}{88}$ (approx $0.27$).

Is there any way to solve this a) for a general $C$, or b) for $C = J\frac{x^2}{1-x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the derivate equal zero in order to get the minima and maxima works on open set. But I assume that you'd like to consider $x,y\in[0,1]$, which is closed. In order to get the maximal value of your function $f$, you have to compare different cases.

1) Interior: Compute the points $(x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,1)$ where $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$. This gives the critical points on the interior of your domain. If you just need the maximal value, then it is sufficient to check which critical point has the highest value.

2) Boundary: Then you have to check the function restricted to the boundary. But you can't use the normal derivate here. And since the boundary is not smooth we have to consider the edges and corner separately.

2 a) Edges: You have four edges: 
$$E_1=\{0\}\times(0,1)\\E_2=\{1\}\times(0,1)\\ E_3=(0,1)\times\{0\}\text{ and }\\E_4=(0,1)\times\{1\}.
$$ 
To get the maximum of $f\mid_{E_1}$ you can define $g_1(y):=f(0,y)=f\mid_{E_1}(x,y)$ and compute the maximum of $g_1$ for $y\in(0,1)$. Then you compute the same way the maximum of $$g_2(y):=f(1,y)=f\mid_{E_2}(x,y)\text{ for }y\in(0,1),\\ g_3(x):=f(x,0)=f\mid_{E_3}(x,y)\text{ for }x\in(0,1)\text{ and }\\g_3(x):=f(x,1)=f\mid_{E_4}(x,y)\text{ for }x\in(0,1)$$.

2 b) Corner: Finally you evaluate $f(0,0)$, $f(1,1)$, $f(0,1)$ and $f(1,0)$.

The biggest value amongst 1), 2a) and 2b) is the maximal value of $f$.

It is also possible that you get no maximal point from 1) or 2a).

**Edit:**

Consider the example $C(x)=\frac1{10}x^2+\frac9{10}x$ and $K=1$. We get
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=(1-(1-x)(1-y))K-C(x)-C(y)\\
&=-xy-\frac1{10}(x^2-x)-\frac1{10}(y^2-y).
\end{align}
1) We compute
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}-y-\frac1{10}(2x-1)\\-x-\frac1{10}(2y-1)\end{pmatrix}
$$
and get
$$
y=-\frac1{10}(2x-1)\\
x=-\frac1{10}(2y-1).
$$
This system yields $(x,y)=\left(\frac1{12},\frac1{12}\right)$. But since your Hessian matrix $H_f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac15 & -1\\-1 & -\frac15\end{pmatrix}$ is indefinite your critical point is a saddle point.

From this we can conclude that the maximum of $f$ has to be on the boundary.

2 a) We consider
$$
g_1(y)=-\frac1{10}(y^2-y)\\
g_2(y)=-\frac1{10}(y^2+9y)\\
g_3(x)=-\frac1{10}(x^2-x)\\
g_4(x)=-\frac1{10}(x^2+9x).
$$
We compute that $g_1$ has a maximal point at $y=\frac12$ and $g_3$ at $x=\frac12$ while $g_2$ and $g_4$ have no critical points in $(0,1)$. We get $g_1\left(\frac12\right)=g_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac1{40}$.

2 b) We compute
$$
f(0,0)=f(0,1)=f(1,0)=0\text{ and }f(1,1)=-1.
$$
Finally we compare the maxima from 2a) and the values from 2b). Since $0<\frac1{40}$ we get that $f$ is maximal at $(0,\frac12)$ and $(\frac12,0)$ with the maximal value $f(0,\frac12)=f(\frac12,0)=\frac1{40}$.

*I just realized that your example is a little bit different. But you can see how it works and use it for your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Under condition you made your problem never have global maximum point! And Why :

Taylor expansion of $C : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ about $x=1$ is 
$$  C(x) = C(1)+C'(1) (x-1) + C''(\zeta) \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} > C(1)+C'(1) (x-1) $$

For some $\zeta $. Therefore

$$       C'(1) (1-x)  + C'(1) (1-y)  \leq  - C(x) - C(y)  $$

So

$$ \left(1 - (1-x)(1-y)\right)K + C'(1) (1-x)  + C'(1) (1-y) \leq   \left(1 - (1-x)(1-y)\right)K - C(x) - C(y) $$

Substituting $ t = (1-x) , ~ s=(1-y) $ we get,

$$ \left(1 - st   \right)K + C'(1) s + C'(1) t\leq  \left(1 - st   \right)K - C(1-s)  C(1-t) $$

Now In left side choosing the path $ s = - t $ and letting $ t \to + \infty $ we get $ \text{Left side} \to + \infty $, therefore $\text{ Right Side } \to + \infty $. So  there is no global maximum .

Comment: My question possibly was not clearly stated. X and y have to be between 0,1. My problem was that I was finding a local maximum that wasn't the highest one for this range.